# trouble with php DomDocument save() to xml

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

i have a trouble with my output file when i use the php domDocument, the output is:

```
<node type="allow" tesst="text"/><node type="allow" text="test2"/>
```

i was expected

```
<node type="allow" tesst="text"/>
**<node type="allow" text="test2"/>
```

can anyone help me?

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8"); 
$xml->load("../export/acl.conf.xml"); 
$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("list")->item(1); 
$dataTag = $xml->createElement("node"); 
$domAttr = $xml->createAttribute('type');
$domAttr->value = "{$acl_type}"; 
$domAt = $xml->createAttribute('cidr'); 
$domAt->value = "{$ipadd}/32"; 
//$domComent = $xml->createComment($_REQUEST['comment']); 
$dataTag->appendChild($domAttr); 
$dataTag->appendChild($domAt); 
$rootTag->appendChild($dataTag); 
$xml->save("../export/acl.conf.xml");
```

Comment: add your code here

Comment: you need to learn how to ask a question properly. By that I mean show us what you have tried. I.e, a code paste

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @Priyank, this is my code 
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml->load("../export/acl.conf.xml");
$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("list")->item(1);
$dataTag = $xml->createElement("node");
$domAttr = $xml->createAttribute('type');
$domAttr->value = "{$acl_type}";
$domAt = $xml->createAttribute('cidr');
$domAt->value = "{$ipadd}/32";
//$domComent = $xml->createComment($_REQUEST['comment']);
$dataTag->appendChild($domAttr);
$dataTag->appendChild($domAt);
$rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);
$xml->save("../export/acl.conf.xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited your answer, but didn't supply an example of the XML you were dealing with!

That said, try using DOMText in conjunction:

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument(); 

$node1 = $xml->createElement("node"); 
$node1->setAttribute('anything', 'whatever');

$text = new DOMText('**');

$node2 = $xml->createElement("node"); 
$node2->setAttribute('another', 'example');

$xml->appendChild($node1);
$xml->appendChild($text);
$xml->appendChild($node2);

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Which would output :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<node anything="whatever"/>**<node another="example"/>
```

Play around with it! Good luck! https://3v4l.org/1kMMD